# Do code in external js file multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

In my index.html file i want to automaticly run a js command three times but i want it located at the same place (in the external js file) for administration. The js is:

```
var links = ['http://cur.lv/yz89', 'http://cur.lv/yz8m', 'http://cur.lv/yzgj',];
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
document.writeln('<a href="' + links[rnd] + '" onclick="hi()" target="_blank">Link</br></a>*');
```

And on the main site i want this code to be runned 3 times (or more) so it will look as this:

```
My ad

Link*

Link*

Link*

My ad
```

How to do this?

Comment: `writeln` with inline `onclick`? I smell refactoring down the road with just 3 lines already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try like this

```
var links = ['http://cur.lv/yz89', 'http://cur.lv/yz8m', 'http://cur.lv/yzgj',];

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
  document.writeln('<a href="' + links[rnd] + '" onclick="hi()" target="_blank">Link</a>*</br>');
}
```

Comment: Your code works almost correctly but as seen on this img <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6VwG0RZ.jpg" alt="" title="Hosted by imgur.com" />
The error is that the links appears above the ad and not centrated...

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches.

1. You can just include the script file three times. (It doesn't matter that it declares global vars, the redeclarations are in-spec and become no-ops.)
2. You can modify the script so it defines a function that does the work, include the script once, then use inline `script` elements to call that function three times.
3. You can modify the script so it defines a function that accepts an argument saying how many times to repeat the `document.write`, putting a `for` loop around that call, and then call that with a `3`.